# How to check if a value already exists to avoid duplicates?If it exist then do nothing otherwise insert record into database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check if an Id already exists in table before I insert a duplicate.

So I need to check the table of database for the presence of the Id and if it exists then do nothing Otherwise I want to insert the record into the table. How can i do this?

**Is there any other way except this:**

```
Sql_query->Select id from table where key="something";

If(true) 
{
  do nothing;
}
else
{
  Insert record in database;
}
```

**I want to avoid this because it requires time to search entire table and then insert.** So is there any feasible way?

Comment: select all from the db where the id matches and check if the count of rows returned is 0 or not.

Comment: @Strawberry : Id is not primary key. So i can not use INSERT IGNORE.

Comment: So what is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @Strawberry : My pimary key is TripId which i didnt written here.

Comment: Note that a key doesn't need to be PRIMARY for this to work.

Comment: @Strawberry : Insert Ignore will be used when there is any error while inserting record. But I dont get any error. but in my case duplicate entries are inserted and my Primary key is auto incremented.So i dont need INSERT IGNORE.

Comment: The incrementing of a PK is irrelevant. If it matters that PKs are incremental and sequential then you should not (despite its name) be using AUTO_INCREMENT for this! The purpose of AUTO_INCREMENT is simply to ensure that values are UNIQUE and, to a lesser extent, sequential. MySQL does not care whether they are incremental, and nor should you!

Comment: @Strawberry : I am saying PK is auto incremented because i dont get any error while inserting record.So I cant use INSERT IGNORE. give me example if you think that i can use insert ignore to avoid duplicate entries.

Comment: ok... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f07e5/1

Comment: @Strawberry : oh,yes with unique keyword your answer is perfect.But in my case I want to check two column values are same with new values respectively. i.e. if b_id=12,c_id=100 then ignore otherwise if b_id=12,c_id=101 then insert or if b_id=13,c_id=100 then insert.Thanks.

Comment: So add a compound index instead UNIQUE(col1,col2)

Comment: @Strawberry :Can't we use this during insert query.Although your answer is perfect.I want to clarify.

Comment: Only in the sense already described below - but I just don't see why you'd want to do that. In any event, best practice dictates that whenever you use a surrogate key (e.g. an autoincrementing id), you should also (where possible) form a natural key on some combination of the remaining columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two strategies:

1. Let the database do this task. Alter your table so the field you want to be unique is actually a [unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html). When you want to insert the data, and it is a duplicate, you'll receive an error which can be used to decide what to do next. Or you might use an [`ON DUPLICATE KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) if you want to do another table operation instead, if needed.
2. Query the table to find out if there the id is already present. If not, generate your insert.

Example:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM yourtable");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    /* do your insert */
}
$result->close();
```

I prefer letting the database do the job.

***Update:***

On request here are two examples on how to add an unique index to your table. The SQL looks like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX your index_name
ON your_table (your_id_field);
```

When inserting data, mysql will throw an error if the key already exists. To work with this error, do something like this:

```
$SQL = 'INSERT INTO yourtable (yourfield1, yourfield2) 
        VALUES ( 1, "Hello")';    
$result = $mysqli->query($SQL);

if (!mysqli_query($link, $SQL)) {
    if(mysqli_errno($link) == 1062) {
         /* duplicate ... whatever you want in this case */
    }
}
```

You don't need all this error handling if you don't want to do anything in this situation of course.

Comment: oh yes..I see first option is my answer.But can you explain 1st option with detail.I dont want to use ON DUPLICATE KEY because i dont want to update. I want to use unique keyword with alter query.Can you please describe in detail or with example.Thank you.

Comment: What kind of example do you expect? PHP code on how to cope with an insert error?

Comment: I want example of this line: Alter your table so the field you want to be unique is actually a unique index.When you want to insert the data, and it is a duplicate, you'll receive an error then do nothing.

Comment: I've added an easy example.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the following code:

```
<?php
   if($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id=?")){
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if($stmt->num_rows == 0){
      // CREATE RECORD
    }
   }
?>
```

You just need to search in the table and check if the query returns something

Comment: if you're going to provide people with mysql_* code at least use the proper escaping to prevent injection and don't hand out faulty code.

Comment: @BramVandenbogaerde I got error here as i follow your answer: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::store_result().

Comment: @FastTrack if you're using PDO my code will not work, this is for mysqli_prepared_statement. I'm sorry if I confused you with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Create unique index on a column (if you are not checking the primary key) and use `ON DUPLICATE` when creatin SQL query. More about this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html