# How do you get which ID's aren't already in the database without selecting the entire database and comparing with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array of ID's that correlate to a unique column in a MySQL table, is there a way to get the ID's from the array that don't appear in the database? I know I could do it by selecting the entire database and doing comparisons with PHP, but the table could get pretty big, so this doesn't seem like a very good idea to me.

Comment: How many ids do you have in PHP?

Comment: Currently around 5k. The database should have a similar number, but slightly less.

Comment: Then the best may be to create a temporary table, insert all the ids and select from a cross join. Can you expand more on the purpose of this operation?

Comment: @deceze Ah, sorry, missed your question, I'm given a list of product codes (refereed to as ids above because they are unique) and the list includes more every month (I think monthly...), I need to do a long process with each one before entering the result into the database and I want to filter it down to ones I haven't done already as the process will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in two stages:

```
$ids = implode(',', $your_array);

SELECT id FROM thetable WHERE id IN ($ids); 

$found_ids = array();
while($row = fetch($result)) {
    $found_ids[] = $row['id'];
}

$missing = array_diff($your_array, $found_ids);
```

Basically: use your array of ids to select any matching records from the DB. Any ids in the array which don't have matching records will obviously not be returned. Take that result set, stuff it into another array. Then do a `diff` between the two arrays. The missing values will pop out as they'll only be in the  original array, not the "found" one.

Comment: Any idea if this would be better or worse performance wise than the other suggestion of creating a temporary table?

Comment: I didn't really want to have to do such a large select from the database, but I personally like this approach a bit better than the temporary table idea.

Comment: I also like the use of array_diff, I would probably had ended up looping myself instead, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE ID NOT IN( your_ids )
```

I have this tested with about 2K array of IDs on oracle and performance is still usable, but I must admit it is not the best solution (Be aware in oracle and other DBs, there is also a constraint to 1K items in IN() condition).

Or you can make temporary table from array of IDs and make JOIN with your table which is a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Define your column(ID) as UNIQUE constraint. And for checking whether it is in database or not : add ignore keyword in insert query.

I have similar question.

You can find your solution here :

[How to check if a value already exists to avoid duplicates?If it exist then do nothing otherwise insert record into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379718/how-to-check-if-a-value-already-exists-to-avoid-duplicatesif-it-exist-then-do-n)

Hope this might help..

Comment: not really an answer. You want to insert, he doesnt want to insert. He wants to simply know what is in the database and what not

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following sql:

```
<?php

$ids = implode(',', $YOUR_ARRAY_OF_IDS);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ID NOT IN(".$ids.") ORDER by ID ASC;"
```

If you don't like to run sql in PHP then you just do the following:

```
<?php

echo $ids = implode(',', $YOUR_ARRAY_OF_IDS);
```

run this code and you will get the *imploded* string. And then you can do the SQL in MySQL or phpMyAdmin.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This won't work as I'm looking for the IDs not in the database, not IDs that aren't in the array.

Comment: No, this will work. You have got my answer reversely. This SQL will not locate the _IDs not present in Array_. This will return the _IDs from your DB which are not matched with the IDs of the Array_.

Comment: I need the ID's present in the array, that aren't in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (t.id + 1) as id from table_name t where not exists (
    select * from table_name t2 where t2.id = (t.id + 1)
)
```

Assuming your IDs are numeric. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately they aren't numeric.

Answer (score -1):

I know what you mean. I misread your problem too and was going to suggest something along the lines above.
I think you are looking for an efficient way to identify the IDs in your array that are not in your table. There isn't really one query way of doing it.
Although I don't do a lot of mysql in my PHP, my work with oracle leans towards looking at preparing a query, using binding variables and looping through your array.

Have you had a look at the prepare method in the Mysqli extension in PHP?

Preparing a query along the lines of "select count(1) from IDTABLE where ID=?" you could use code similar to the example in the PHP manual for the function/method:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

It looks promising to me.

The code would be something like this:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$ID = 0;

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM IDTABLE ID=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $ID);

    $not_in=array();
    $in=array();
    foreach ($my_ids as $ID) {

      /* execute query */
      $stmt->execute();

      /* bind result variables */
      $stmt->bind_result($matches);

      /* fetch value */
      $stmt->fetch();

      if ($matches == 0) {
        $not_in[]=$ID;
      } else {
        $in[]=$ID;
      }

    }
    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Not sure if you can move the $stmt->bid_result() up beside the bind_param - before the loop.

Any Help?

Comment: ouch... you're basically executing a query for EVERY SINGLE value the might not be in the array, instead of doing a `where not in (...)` single query. talk about inefficient.

Comment: The point is that he wants to find which elements of his array are not in the table NOT which entries on his table are not in his array. the not in (...) is not an answer to his problem.

Comment: `select * from table where foo not in (1,2,3)` would return just that. just pass in all of the "here's what I have" values into the not-in field and you'll get back the table entries that ARENT't in that list.

Comment: Sorry Marc but I'm sure you've got the wrong end of the stick. John clearly wants the elements of his php array that are not in the table. This is not the same as finding entries on the table that are not in his array. Say his array is (1,2,3,4) and his table contains 1 and 3 - I think he wants to return (2,4).

Comment: You're right... apologies. But still, there's better ways to do what you're doing. running N queries when a single one will do is generally bad idea.

Comment: I'm not a mysql expert and usually work with oracle backends but sometimes there is no way to avoid iterative querying. The best you can do is remove repeated parsing etc. using bind variables helps with database optimisation of queries. Mysql doesn't pretend to be as powerful as oracle in that regard but I think the mysqli_prepare will help a little.